# jQuery for clicking on a button which fades out one div and then fades in another and then to do it in reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you write jQuery for clicking on a button which fades out one div and then fades in another and then clicking another button that does the reverse.

I am really stuck at the half way mark. With the code below I am able to fade out the div and fade in another but unsure on how to do the opposite.

Could really do with your expert help on this task. Would be much appreciated - thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#triggerButton1').click(function(e){
        $('#homepagetext').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#contactform').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
    $('#triggerButton2').click(function(e){
        $('#contactform').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('#homepagetext').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You already did the half. Keep passing call back function like you did in the first. `$('#contactform').fadeIn('slow',/* add call back here */);` then fade out that div add that another call back and fade in the other div.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/05q2m4to/
The only thing that seems weird to me is having one fade go `fast` and all the other ones `slow` but that doesn't break anything.

Maybe the problem is somewhere outside the script?

Comment: Found a bug as if you click 1 button and directly the other while the first div is animating, then it show both

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that. Added `stop()` on all the animations, now it should be fine. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g8tr4obp/